# Need help simplifying final expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I was carrying out a function and ended up with the desired answer, but for some reason, *Mathematica* keeps giving me the answer in a strange numerical form.

```
SIMP[a_, b_, n_] := (1/3)[(b - a)/n][
  Sum[f[a + (2 x - 2) (b - a)/n] + 4 f[a + (2 x - 1) (b - a)/n] + 
    f[a + 2 x (b - a)/n], {x, 1, n/2}]]

SIMP[0, 2, 8]
(* (1/3)[1/4][
 f[0] + 4 f[1/4] + 2 f[1/2] + 4 f[3/4] + 2 f[1] + 4 f[5/4] + 
  2 f[3/2] + 4 f[7/4] + f[2]] *)

Clear[f]
f[x_] := 1/(1 + x^6)
SIMP[0, 2, 8]
(* (1/3)[1/4][557032465187652359/44540986037769325] *)
```

All I need is for the output to turn into a numerical value with 6 decimal places, but it stays in this form. Any advice?

Comment: Please take a look at other Simpson integrators. For example [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23388/193), but there are a lot around

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You should use square brackets only to group arguments of functions and not as parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f,sIMP];
sIMP[a_, b_, n_] := (1/3) ((b - a)/n) 
          Sum[ f[a + (2 x - 2) (b - a)/n] + 4 f[a + (2 x - 1) (b - a)/n] + 
               f[a + 2 x (b - a)/n], {x, 1, n/2}]
f[x_] := 1/(1 + x^6)
sIMP[0, 2, 8] // N

(* 1.0421720807799113` *)
```

Comment: Square brackets and parentheses are different beasts in Mathemtica